# How do you enable new navigation sidebar in Jira?

Tags: gui, user-interface, navigation, jira, jira-agile

I really like the new navigation sidebar in Jira onDemand:

[image]

The only problem is, when I created a new project on a new account, the sidebar has gone. Is there any way to enable it for all projects?

Comment: How do you even enable it for a single project?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I like it too. Enough so to have documented it in an in-house Jira user guide before realizing that it was not visible to my target users... Argh.

To enable this feature for ***all users/projects*** on your instance:

```
<INSTANCE_URL>/secure/admin/SiteDarkFeatures!default.jspa
```

where  is the first part of the URL that you use to access your JIRA instance.

Then, in the **Enable dark feature** field, enter

```
com.atlassian.jira.projects.ProjectCentricNavigation
```

and finally, click **Add**

Not sure what the equivalent is for activating just for oneself, unfortunately. Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm not allowed to comment but I'll add this as "answer" material... In addition to the dark feature given by Patterson, I also found this 'site wide dark feature' string: com.atlassian.jira.projects.ProjectCentricNavigation.Switch Sadly, I have no way of knowing what it would be to disable that one.